# inputAccessoryView Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a textView docked to the bottom of the view. However, the keyboard wont dismiss when the user taps outside the commentTextView.

Current Attempt:

```
import UIKit
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var commentBar: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var commentTextField: UITextField!

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        return commentBar
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        commentBar.removeFromSuperview()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        return false;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: you are accessing commentTextField and in question you are telling textview. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 7):

According to Apple's documentation, the keyboard won't dismiss by default when the user taps outside of the `UITextView`. You do need to handle this programmatically when you want to dismiss the keyboard by calling `commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()`.

[**UITextFiled Reference about Managing the Keyboard**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html)

> It is your application’s responsibility to dismiss the keyboard at the time of your choosing. You might dismiss the keyboard in response to a specific user action, such as the user tapping a particular button in your user interface. To dismiss the keyboard, send the resignFirstResponder message to the text view that is currently the first responder.

There are many ways for a user may hide the keyboard.

**Situation 1**: one is when the user tap on the *Return* button on the keyboard. This is exactly what your following function is for:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}
```

But the major problem is that the above function won't get called because you forget to set the `UITextFieldDelegate`. In short, you need to change the class definition to the following:

```
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate /*Add This*/, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // ....
}
```

You will also have to set the delete either in the storyboard or by code. It is the same as setting the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. By the following is an example of setting it in code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    commentTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

**Situation 2**: when user tap on the table view. You can simply implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` and it should work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder();
}
```

**Situation 3**: when the user tap on a background view. This is what the following code is for. However, this function will not get called when user is tap on the table view. If you want to know why, please refer to the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) for more details.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // self.view.endEditing(true); // This line is redundant. 
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

To sum up, there is no quick and easy way to dismiss the keyboard say "when the user taps outside the textView". You do need to handle all different situations according to your need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. I tried this out but the keyboard still does not disappear even if I hit "return" or tap the tableView.

Comment: @Emma, I guess your `commentBar` may be problematic. Could you try remove that and see how it works? Reading the [Text Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html), I am not sure whether it will work or not by returning an IBOutLet for the inputAccessoryView.

Comment: even when using only textfield and removing commentBar, I have the same issue. I also tried added TextField delegate to the class and setting it to self in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Emma, could you set break point in these functions or add logs to see whether they are executed at all? If they are, what is the value of `commentTextField` when the function is called? Is it nil? I am guessing that the `@IBOutlet` may not be set properly.

Answer (score 4):

Try to set keyboard resign on your tableview as shown in figure.

check any 
-dismiss on drag
-dismiss interactively

[image: Set keyboard release on tableview interations]

Comment: Dismiss interactively doesn't seem to have any affect. However, dismiss on drag does dismiss the keyboard. How can I make dismiss interactively work?

Comment: Dismss on drag : when you drag tableview up or down keyboard dismiss quickly
Dismiss interatively : when you drag tableview down keyboard dismiss slowly with your intensity of draging, just like you make a pan gesture to move your keyboard down.

Answer (score 1):

did you add `Table View`?

if yes, `tableViewCell` will receive the touch event instead of `controller.view`.

you could override the method in custom tableView cell:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if (xxTextField.isFirstResponder){
            return viewController.view
        }
   return self 
}
```

Another way you can try,maybe it work:

add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `controller.view`.

Comment: That is correct, there is a tableview. When using the hitTest method, I get `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

Comment: @Emma,you should override in your `UITableViewCell`,not `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "outside of my UITextField", I'm guessing you mean "on another element in my view". I can see that you have a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, which tells me you have a `tableView` inside `CommentsViewController`.

You can implement the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` and there you can resign the keyboard by calling `commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: I tried it with @yuchen's answer, but it does not resign the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

First, your view controller needs to implement UITextFieldDelegate, so add that. Then, set your view controller as the delegate for the textfield

[image]

then add these methods. The first one will resignFirstResponder when your text field ends editing. The second resigns when you hit return. The last forces your textfield to end editing when you tap the background.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
} 

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.commentTextField.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

To

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

It should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true);
    commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: @Emma it is a new collection type in Swift 1.2, to replace the Objective-C `NSSet`.