# Dismiss Keypad when clicking UITextView or by clicking return/done?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm in the process of programming my first application and I'm having trouble dismissing the numeric keypad when I click off of it. When I click on the background it dismisses, but when I try to click on a UITextView, it doesn't dismiss. Also, there is no "Done" or "Return" button on the numeric keypad? Please be in-depth because I'm not totally sure how everything works just yet! Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var CalcButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var DaysLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var RateLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CowsLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PoundsLabel: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var PoundsTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CowsTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var DaysTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var RateTextfield: UITextField!

    @IBAction func NDHIALink(sender: AnyObject) {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.dhia.org/")!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.DaysLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.RateLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.CowsLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.PoundsLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.CalcButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        DaysTextfield.delegate = self
        PoundsTextfield.delegate = self
        RateTextfield.delegate = self
        CowsTextfield.delegate = self
        self.CowsLabel.delegate = self
        self.PoundsLabel.delegate = self
        self.RateLabel.delegate = self
        self.DaysLabel.delegate = self
        DaysTextfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        CowsTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        PoundsTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        DaysTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        RateTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
        CowsLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        PoundsLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        DaysLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        RateLabel.resignFirstResponder()    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836514/inputaccessoryview-dismiss-keyboard/30217191#30217191 has some information on dismissing the keyboard

Comment: look in to `textFieldShouldReturn` and `UITextInputTraits`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if everyone understood my question correctly, however, I did find a solution! What I wanted to do was stop editing a textfield when I clicked on a non-editable textview or the background. Thanks to those who helped earlier! Here's the solution:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSingleTap:")
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

}
```

func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

```
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UiTextView you ar touching has the "editable" property set to "YES" the keyboard won't dismiss as it will become the first responder again. If you don't need to edit the text on it, set the property to "NO" (or uncheck it from Interface Builder).

Comment: I already have the UITextView set to "NO" for if it's editable or not :/